# how to array list to tree in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a list:

```
var list = ['parent-element', 'child-of-previus-element-1', 'child-of-previus-element-2'];
```

where each next element in the array is a child of the previous.

I want to transform this list into a tree structure, e.g.:

```
{
    "parent-element": {
        "childrens": [{
            "child-of-previus-element-1": {
                "childrens": [{
                    "child-of-previus-element-2": {
                        "childrens": []
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I have tried:

```js
var list = ['parent-element', 'child-of-previus-element-1', 'child-of-previus-element-2'];
var tree = {};

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if( list[i-1] &&  tree[list[i-1]] ){
      tree[list[i-1]].childrens[list[i]] = {"childrens": []}; 
    } else {
      tree[list[i]] = {
        "childrens": []
      };
    }
}

console.log( JSON.stringify(tree) );
```

but the output is:

```
{
    "parent-element":{
        "childrens":[]
     },
     "child-of-previus-element-2":{
        "childrens":[]
     }
}
```

Comment: That "treelike structure" is invalid.

Comment: sorry, fixed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might reduce it right:

```js
var list = ['parent-element', 'child-of-previus-element-1', 'child-of-previus-element-2'];

var tree = list.reduceRight((child, key) => ({ [key]: { children: [child] } }), null);

console.log(JSON.stringify(tree))
```

Comment: @ar099968 glad to help :)

Comment: Good solution, but downplaying other peoples problems with "too easy" feels kinda off..., no offense. (Still upvoted because you solved while I was still thinking about it :) )